# Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, rest-security

I have a script that calls a webservice over https. When I build with swagger in C# Mono for Unity I get:

> Error calling AuthenticatePost: Error getting response stream (Write:
>   The authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure

I already imported all the certifies from the moztools.exe and even used certmgr.exe to add the url from where I call the webservice, but it still doesn't work.

Now I'm using ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback but it never enters my callback, here is my code:

```
    // Inside a prefab that runs before any webcall
    void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEnable********");

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback;
    }

public static bool RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("MyRemoteCertificateValidationCallback");
    bool isOk = true;
    // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.ChainStatus.Length; i++)
        {
            if (chain.ChainStatus[i].Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown)
            {
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
                chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllFlags;
                bool chainIsValid = chain.Build((X509Certificate2)certificate);
                if (!chainIsValid)
                {
                    isOk = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return isOk;
}
```

Why doesn't it work even when I add the certificates? Why is the delegate callback not being called?

Client code:

```
public Object CallApi(String path, RestSharp.Method method, Dictionary<String, String> queryParams, String postBody,
        Dictionary<String, String> headerParams, Dictionary<String, String> formParams, 
        Dictionary<String, FileParameter> fileParams, String[] authSettings)
    {
    var request = new RestRequest(path, method);


    //UpdateParamsForAuth(queryParams, headerParams, authSettings);

    // add default header, if any
    foreach(var defaultHeader in _defaultHeaderMap)
        request.AddHeader(defaultHeader.Key, defaultHeader.Value);

    // add header parameter, if any
    foreach(var param in headerParams)
        request.AddHeader(param.Key, param.Value);

    // add query parameter, if any
    foreach(var param in queryParams)
        request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

    // add form parameter, if any
    foreach(var param in formParams)
        request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

    // add file parameter, if any
    foreach(var param in fileParams)
        request.AddFile(param.Value.Name, param.Value.Writer, param.Value.FileName, param.Value.ContentType);

    if (postBody != null) // http body (model) parameter
        request.AddParameter("application/json", postBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    return (Object)RestClient.Execute(request);
}
```

I also tried loading the certificate into the RestClient before doing Execute. It does load the certificate but it still throws the same error. To load the certificate I used:

```
    X509Certificate2 certificates = new X509Certificate2();
    certificates.Import("-vizzariocom.crt");

    RestClient.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificates };
    return (Object)RestClient.Execute(request);
```

Comment: If you expect to enter to the function RemoteCertificateValidationCallback your code is wrong, you're supplying a lambda so it will execute the lambda. Also, this must be done only once, not each time you do a web request, else you will end with a ton of hooked lambdas to the same event.

Comment: I took out the call to my callback and put it in a new script inside a prefab that runs at the beggining of the game, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you verified this time the validation callback is executed?

Comment: Also, the code looks wrong, the hook should be `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertificateValidationCallback;`

Comment: Yeah I try  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertificateValidationCallback; and although it executes the onEnable, it never gets into the callback

Comment: That's very strange, is it possible you're using a component which also uses the ServerCertificateValidationCallback?

Comment: I search in the whole solution and only where I used ServerCertificateValidationCallback was where I found a reference.

Comment: But are you using any component in the game? I don't mean your own components I mean any type of asset from the store which may interfere with this.

Comment: I´m using UniRx, RestSharp tailored for Unity, NewtonSoft tailored for Unity and a client build with Swagger that I generated from a YML. I looked inside the swagger client code, and didn´t found any reference to ServerCertificateValidationCallback .

Comment: If your client uses UniRx to call the URL observableWWW does not trigger ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback, check this, it may help: https://gitter.im/neuecc/UniRx?at=581354c0806316005dccd0d1 Go a bit up and you will find a solution for it.

Comment: Unfortunalty my swagger client doesnt work directly with UniRX, I used UniRx for other stuff not related with the webservice call.

Comment: Maybe if you add the client code something can be seen on it.